# limits and max, what is true?

Tags: calculus

Hi I have two equations that may be True and may be False:
$a_1,a_2,... a_k$ are real positive numbers

A)
 [image: Question A]

B)
[image: Question B]

Now for me it looks like A lim is something like $a_1 + a_2 + ... a_k$
And about B I really dont know.

I dont have a method i just imagine that n is extremely large number and then remove the meaningless values from the equation (like static numbers) but this method is not that great since in B for example i really can't know what will happen and this method is error prone anyway.

How would you solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: You can estimate the sum $a_1^n + a_2^n + \ldots + a_k^n$ by $kA^n$ where $A$ denotes $\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. And below by $A^n$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I thought about it too but wasn't sure it is right so if we do it we can say that question A is true and I guess it means that B is false (though they both can be true) but most importantly it means that there is no real method to do it? just think logically what would happen with giant number?

Comment: No, you can say that the first term is bounded above by $\sqrt[n]{\frac{kA^n}{k}} = A$, and bounded below by $\sqrt[n]{\frac{A^n}{k}} = \frac{A}{\sqrt[n]{k}}$ which tends to $A$ as well for $n$ to infinity. Something similar is true for the second one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh ok I see thanks, but can we say that the bounded below part = A too because the denominator is really close to 1?

Comment: A standard limit is that $\sqrt[n]{k} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and also for $\sqrt[n]{n}$.